# Continuous function by parts.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $c>0$ be a parameter and consider the function:
$f(x;c) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } x\leq c \\
  (\frac{2}{3}(x-c))^{3/2} & \mbox{if } x > c
 \end{array}
\right.
$

Show that this function is continuous.

My proof is: since 0 with $x\leq c$ and $(2/3(x-c))^{3/2}$ are cont. functions, is enough to check the continuity at $x=c$.
taking limits, $\lim_{x\to c^-} y(x;c)$ is equal to $0$
and $\lim_{x\to c^+} y(x;c)$ is also equal to $0$
hence, since both limits exist and are equal, $y(x;c)$ is cont. at $x=c$.

My problem is that I´d like to have a more formal proof, also if mine isn't correct, let me know.
 thanks for your help

Comment: Your proof is correct. What do you mean by 'more formal'?

Comment: perhaps by using definition of continuity, but someone has already showed me how to.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning can be resumed as

"Let $f:[-\infty,c]\rightarrow R $ , $g:[c,\infty]\rightarrow R $ with $f(c)=g(c)$ continuous then

$h(x) :=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  f(x)  & \mbox{if } x\leq c \\
  g(x) &\mbox{if } x > c
 \end{array}
\right.$

is continous on $R$"

It's not hard to check this is true using the definition of continuity.

Comment: True, thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Will procede that way.

Comment: You are welcome,!